# Merge lists in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and a list of `cols=['a', 'b', 'c', ...]` as a subset of the columns of `df`. Each column in `cols` is a list object in the dataframe. Is there a way I could aggregate the lists to a single list by concatenating all lists in `cols`?

Comment: `df[cols].sum(1)`?

Comment: Can you try `df['combined']= df[cols].values.tolist()`